# how to measure the payload size for Azure Table Entity Group Transaction?

Tags: azure-table-storage, entity-group-transactions

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx),

- The transaction can include at most 100 entities, and its total payload may be no more than 4 MB in size.

Question) Before sending a group-transaction request, how can we measure the payload size in order to guarantee that the size does not exceed 4MB?

thanks in advance!